# Logic article on first-order invariants of abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, abelian-groups

I remember reading an article published in the 1970s by a Polish mathematician describing the first-order invariants of a torsion-free abelian group. I do not recollect the author's name, the title of the article or the publication.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(Not Ulm invariants, and definitely torsion-free)

Comment: Not Polish or 1970's, but Ulm invariants for groups sounds similar.  Maybe look at papers citing Ulm?  Gerhard "Maybe No Parentheses Were Used?" Paseman, 2017.11.09.

Comment: OK.  How about Eklof or Szmielew?  Gerhard "Is Getting Warmer Or Colder?" Paseman, 2017.11.09.

Comment: Thank you Gerhard "Is Getting Warmer Or Colder?" Paseman. I was out by 15 years but it was indeed

Comment: Szmielew, W. (1955), "Elementary properties of Abelian groups", Fundamenta Mathematicae, 41: 203–271

Answer (score 2):

Szmielew, W. (1955), *[Elementary properties of Abelian groups](https://eudml.org/doc/urn:eudml:doc:213354)*, Fundamenta Mathematicae, 41: 203–271.

Comment: BTW it addresses all abelian groups, not only torsion-free ones. Also, it does model theory without the modern language and without using ultrafilters.

Comment: W is for Wanda.  Her history also makes for an interesting read.  Gerhard "Making My History Also Interesting" Paseman, 2020.01.30.